# When can a javascript array store elements in key: value pairs with keys having 'string' values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

It's said that everything in javascript is an object. So, to understand the concept in detail I wrote the following code but got some unexpected results.

```js
var color = [];
console.log(color.constructor === Array);
color[color['purple'] = 2] = 'green';
console.log(color);
console.log(color.constructor === Array);
console.log(Array.isArray(color));
```

According to my understanding, arrays can only hold values when their keys are number. To store key as a string we use objects. However, the above code resulted in this.

```
true
[ <2 empty items>, 'green', purple: 2 ]
true
true
```

`typeof color` will result in `object` but that's a generic case for all arrays. How is `purple: 2` a valid element inside the `color` variable? Shouldn't `color` be an object rather than an array? Or is there any other inbuilt method with which I can check a variable is an array or an object?

These type of questions have been asked before but the scenarios were somewhat different. I looked for this specific case but didn't get any satisfying result.

Comment: Arrays are objects and the keys can be any string value. It's *usually* not a great idea to use non-numeric keys, but there's nothing fundamentally wrong with it. The numeric keys are in fact always interpreted as strings anyway.

Answer (score 5):

`color` is an array. All arrays extend objects. In this line you are doing two things (very unusual syntax, probably not what you intended):

`color[color['purple'] = 2] = 'green'`

1: `color.purple = 2` does not add an element to the array. It set a property of `purple` on the object `color`.

2: `color[2] = green` The above assignment statement resolves to (returns) the value 2. That means that you are assigning `color[2]` in this case.

3: Because the array has a value at index 2, it also has space allocated for index 0 and 1 (the two blanks)

Integer properties are elements of the array. All other properties are general properties that are the same for all objects. If you look at `color.length` you will see that is 3 in this case: `[undefined, undefined, green]`. By adding additional properties to the array, you are basically extending the array interface to a custom Array-like object.

Refer to this second paragraph [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description):

> Arrays cannot use strings as element indexes (as in an associative array) but must use integers. Setting or accessing via non-integers using bracket notation (or dot notation) will not set or retrieve an element from the array list itself, but will set or access a variable associated with that array's object property collection. The array's object properties and list of array elements are separate, and the array's traversal and mutation operations cannot be applied to these named properties.

Comment: I understood your answer but my question is How is 'purple' a valid key for an array?

Comment: Looping through all the properties using 'for in' loop will result in '2 purple'. The results are very unexpected.

Comment: That's a whole new question. Which is answered on here already. `for ... in` iterates over properties names of an object. `Array.forEach` iterates over array elements. `for ... of` iterates over properties that are defined as `iterable`

Answer (score 0):

From MDN

> Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations. Neither the length of a JavaScript array nor the types of its elements are fixed. Since an array's length can change at any time, and data can be stored at non-contiguous locations in the array, JavaScript arrays are not guaranteed to be dense; this depends on how the programmer chooses to use them. In general, these are convenient characteristics; but if these features are not desirable for your particular use, you might consider using typed arrays.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description

Answer (score 0):

`color[color['purple'] = 2] = 'green';`

Let's break it down. First it does `color['purple'] = 2`. This results in color being: `[purple: 2]`. If you execute `var color = []; color['purple'] = 2;` in the console now, the output will be 2.

So, after execution of inner statement, the equivalent statement is `color[2] = 'green'`. Since, this is a numerical assignment, it assigns value 'green' to 3rd element of array (position 2), and also creates two empty items at position 0 and position 1.

Hence, the output: `[<2 empty items>, green, purple: 2]`

@js1568 Well written answer. Kudos.

@Kartik Chauhan To answer your main question - How is 'purple' a valid key for an array?

JS arrays are not just numerically accessible arrays. They are more like maps, where the key can be any object. You can try this code in the browser console.

`var x = []; x[{name: "Kartik"}] = 25; x[{name: "Kartik"}];`

and the output will be 25.

Hence, value purple is a valid key for an array.

Comment: Technically, any value is valid for an object property, not an array element. Your key is not an array element. If you check `x.length === 0`, you will see you did not add anything to the array. See my reference from MDN.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was actually not aware of the fact that it adds as a property and not a key. I just verified and you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. the sentence that said `"everything in JavaScript is an Object"` is totally wrong.
2. in JavaScript arrays are a subtype of the object with special functionalities for ds management, so you can do everything with an array as an object and expect that still be an array.
3. also `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `Function`, etc. are all a subtype of the object in JavaScript and they are not a primary type while `typeof` statement just returns the root primary type of a variable.

according to the above principles your results that you get make sense.

to ensure that variable really is an array I think `Array.isArray` function is the safe option that added in `ECMAScript 5`.

and finally, I strongly suggest you read a piece of great `YDKJS book series` about Objects:

https://github.com/Mahdimeraji07/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch3.md